# Почему IIFE стрелочная функция не работает, когда работает обычная IIFE?

Tags: javascript

Почему такой код работает:

```js
(function() {
  console.log(10);
}());
```

А такой же код, но уже через стрелочную функцию - не работает:

```js
(() => {
  console.log(10);
}());
```

И чтобы заработало нужно писать так:

```js
(() => {
  console.log(10);
})();
```

Comment: синтаксический так предусмотрено, что анонимная стрелочная функция должна быть обернута в скобки

Comment: @Air именно это и непонятно, почему синтаксически так предусмотрено) Я не автор вопроса, но ответы вида «так надо» лично меня тоже не устраивают

Comment: @andreymal, предлагаешь спецификацию процитировать? :)

Comment: @Grundy если в ней есть ответ на вопрос «почему», то да)

Comment: @andreymal, в ней все есть :)

Comment: @Air, хочется понимать логически, в чем же разница. Ведь и там и там function expression, но длинный вариант может вызываться сразу после закрывающейся скобки, а сокращенный нет.

Comment: Синтаксический анализатор работает по разному для анонимных функций и для стрелочных функций. Где-то ломается готовность стрелочной функции к выполнению в анализаторе и получается ошибка. А вот за подробностями действительно нужно идти в спецификацию и выстраивать полную картину))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, с этим моментом какое-то время была путаница: форму, которая сейчас вызывает ошибку, поддерживали некоторые версии движков, Babel, линтеры.

Причина разницы парсинга в том, что обычная функция и стрелочная по спецификации относятся к разным синтаксическим сущностям (CallExpression vs AssignmentExpression), и после подвида стрелочной функции не могут стоять скобки вызова.

Если погуглить, можно понатыкаться на объяснения:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/828

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34589765/2625560

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2118

Answer (score 0):

Ответ понятно что таков синтаксис. Я просто думаю, сделано так чтоб не чесались руки сделать простую замену `function ()` на `() =>` во всех проектах не глядя. Хотя бы потому что контекст `this` в стрелочной функции и в обычной отличаются.

Comment: O_o современные редакторы вроде позволяют делать такие замены на раз-два, если уж руки правда зачешутся. Кажется автору интресует, как работает парсер JS )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, возможно вы правы, но я думаю автор искал "хочется понимать логически"

Comment: На счёт замены ее сделать можно на раз два и получить тонну проблем